# Selenium: Call method every time a page loads

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to throw an exception each time a certain text appears on a page. For this to be practical, a method should check every time a page has finished loading if the exception should be thrown or not. The main problem I'm having right now is with clicks, AKA when a new page is opened as a result of a click on a WebElement.

How can one achieve that custom methods are always called when a page is finished with loading?

Comment: You can use `document.readyState` to check page is loaded completely or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

When we use the WebDriver through the default configuration the attribute `pageLoadStrategy` is set to `normal` which implies that once the page loading is totally complete the `document.readyState` is set to `complete` that is when WebDriver performs the next action as per your script.

Now if you want to be convinced by yourself that the `document.readyState` is set to `complete` you can implement the following code block in your script with the help of a `EplicitWait` for a status log on your console:

```
IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00));
wait.Until(driver => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.